# iCloud Drive Folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, icloud

I have an OSX app that uses iCloud documents with the older Team ID ubiquity key. Does anyone know how to get the ubiquity folder to appear in the iCloud drive folder?

I have already tried using the NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic key set to true in the applications pList to no effect.

Folders that appear in the iCloud drive include Apple's application, and Pixelmator.

Comment: Hi Andy, were you able to solve this? I ran into the same issue.

Comment: No, I haven't solved it yet. :( I haven't had the time to find out what I did wrong though. Have you tried everything Maximilian suggested below?

Comment: We managed to finally get it to work by doing everything Maximilian suggested including keys and build number. I think the build number must be higher? The build must be run at least once too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add these values to your info.plist file and **change your build number**.

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
    <dict>
        <key>iCloud.com.example.app</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
            <string>App name to display in iCloud Drive</string>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
            <string>None</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

and add these keys to your entitlements, you will see an error on the iCloud section of capabilities, but its working fine. So DO NOT click the fix button or change it from the capabilities or it will not work anymore.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
        <array>
            <string>iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
        </array>
        <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
        <array>
            <string>CloudDocuments</string>
        </array>
        <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've already tried those keys except for NSUbiquitousDisplaySet. I'm also using the team ID prefix instead of the iCloud prefix otherwise existing users would lose their files. Will the folder show up in development? or does it only happen on submission to the app store?

Comment: How are you getting the ubiquity container?

Comment: I'm just using NSOpenPanel for opening files to the user. [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]; will return the correct folder inside the iCloud Drive, just the folder isn't visible in the main iCloud drive folder.

Comment: Where are you checking the iCloud folder also? I have found that OS X iCloud Drive folder only shows items with files inside, if you go to iCloud.com though every app shows that is enabled.

Comment: My app isn't showing at iCloud.com either. I'm pretty sure it isn't empty though as I have saved some files in it. I'm going to try those keys again and get back.

Comment: Has this got anything to do with iTunesConnect's iCloud Display Sets?

Comment: I think so, I just saw it and looked like it was included when adding the iCloud. I didn't really do anything fancy to get my app to show up. I know i added those keys to the info.plist. it could be your entitlements though! Thats it. Let me get the stuff you will need.

Comment: Checkout the edit I did to the post, I forgot those. That is how you get it to work.

Comment: Haven't sorted it out yet as I have problems with provisioning profiles but thanks for at least trying to help Maximillian.

Comment: YES. It seems that the problem was mainly me not changing my build number. Thank you thank you thank you!