# iCloud app name missing in open dialog box, no app documents folder

Tags: xcode, macos, icloud, icloud-drive

I seem to have configured iCloud Document Storage incorrectly for my Mac app. In the open dialog, the app's name is blank:

[image: Open dialog in my app]

And when I click on the app name, I'm directed to the iCloud Drive's root folder instead of the app documents folder.

Here's what this looks like in Pages:

[image: Open dialog in Pages]

Things look ok in both Xcode and in Member Center:

[image: iCloud xcode setup]

[image: Member center container]

I tried changing to "Use default container" in Xcode but I encountered the same behavior. (Note: I'm using a shared container between Mac and iOS versions of my app, hence the custom container)

**UPDATE**

I added the following to the Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
<dict>
    <key>iCloud.com.audulus.audulus</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
        <string>Audulus</string>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
        <string>Any</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

(as recommended here: [iCloud Drive Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865643/icloud-drive-folder))

Now, the app documents folder appears, but the app name is still blank in the left column:

[image: App folder appears, but app name still blank on left]

**UPDATE 2**

After creating some documents on the iOS version of my app, I noticed that two folders appear in the drop down menu at the top of the dialog:

[image: Two iCloud folders]